# How to print the first elements of an array according to an int?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of chars, I need to print in the console its first chars according to an int, so if the int is equal to 3, it should print args[0], args[1], args[2]. If the int is 7 it should print the first seven args.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);
    char[] arguments = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    scanner.close();

    int i1 = 0;

    while (i1 <= arguments.length) {        

        System.out.println("???");
        i1 = i1++;

    }
```

The int can be every number, so I can't just do a switch statement because it would be too long. And the elements must be in the same line. Input should be like "ABCDEF"/"ABC".

Comment: Loop `for(int i =0; i < num; i++) { System.out.println(arguments[i]);}` where `num` is the int

Comment: That's almost the same thing that I wrote, I need a single System.out.println(); in which there are the elements. However thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);
        // array of characters given by user
        char[] arguments = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
        // the value of int given by user i.e how many characters need to print
        int intNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        // closing the connection for scanner
        scanner.close();
        //for loop that execute till the given value of int
        for(int i=0; i<intNumber; i++) {
            //condition check to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            if(i < arguments.length)
            // For printing characters in single line
            System.out.print(arguments[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Is there any method to print them in the same line and not a line for each char? ?cause it does not work.

Comment: System.out.print(arguments[i]); - this prints character in single line

Comment: System.out.println(arguments[i]); - this will print each character in new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Index provided by user
int index = input.nextInt();

//For loop which iterates over the array from the beginning to the input index
for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < index; currentIndex++) {
    //Printing the current array character
    System.out.print(arr[currentIndex]);
}
//Printing line when loop has finished traversing
System.out.println();
```

Comment: I need all the elements according to the int in the same line. So like "ABCD" if the int is 4.

Comment: It should work as it is, just remove the space I put, if you want the output to be exactly as you have just specified

Comment: If (for example) the args are {A,B,C,D,E,F} and the int is 3 it prints:
A
B
C (each in different lines)
But I need them like it print arg[0], arg[1], arg[2] so:
ABC (same line, same )

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @Prateek well I thought that the code, being a basic for-loop which is also quite concise in this scenario, would require minimal effort to follow and adding an explanation would just be superfluous

Comment: I agree with Prateek, code need explanation even for its author. Add some and you will improve yourself.

Comment: @linuxfan There, I fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(0, num).forEach(x -> System.out.print(charArray[x]));
```

If you prefer Java8, this code snippet will help you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want top use Streams, why not:

```
String s = scanner.nextLine();
int end = Math.min(n,s.length());
System.out.println( s.substring(0,end) );
```

where n is the number of characters?

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked!! <3
I can use it for my purpose.